# Can a JSP with JSTL tags be included in a ZK (zul) page?

Tags: jsp, jstl, zk

My front-end stack is Spring MVC + ZK + JSP
I have a jsp that has some legacy code and I need to include it within my ZUL page. The jsp has some JSTL tags  and . I have tried a few approaches but haven't got the jsp page to render correctly.

My question is, Can this approach be achieved? I have seen the same question asked a few times in the ZK forum with vague answers. 
If this approach is possible, please help me with a working example and the configuration settings that I would need in the applicationContext.xml

Many Thanks, John

Answer (score 1):

tomyeh (founder of zk) says [here](http://forum.zkoss.org/question/3697/how-to-use-jsp-directive-in-zk/) :

"ZK doesn't take JSP directive. To use JSP with ZK, you have to use ZK as filter to post-process JSP's output. "

Common approach is using zk tags in jsp page. [ZK JSP tags](http://www.zkoss.org/product/zkjsp.dsp) should do this trick.

Please refer :
http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Performance_Tips/Use_ZK_JSP_Tags_instead_of_ZK_Filter

http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Integration/Presentation_Layer/JSP

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/ZK/How-Tos/Integrate-Other-Frameworks#Struts_.2B_Tiles_.2B_JSP_.28.2B_Spring.29

http://www.packtpub.com/article/integrating-zk-with-other-frameworks

Comment: perhaps I understood your answer wrong but it seems you are pointing me to documentation to use ZK tags in a JSP while what I need is to use JSP tags in a ZK page.